# Combining multiple bands from different image collection into one collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I did some calculations on variety of image collections and have generated products and saved them in variables, say a, b and c. Now I want to combine all these products (All one bands) into a multiband image collection.

What function should i use?
I tried with:

```
a.combine(b).combine(c)
a.merge(b).merge(c)
a.add(b).add(c)
```

But, these functions are not working.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you made a unique name for each band, and that you want to obtain one image with 3 bands (one for `a`, one for `b` and one for `c`) you have to `addBands`, like this:

```js
var a = ee.Image(1).rename('one') // product one
var b = ee.Image(2).rename('two')
var c = ee.Image(3).rename('three')

var final = a.addBands([b, c])
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5c3ceef589fc8cbe6036f8f2ef22f2ca

Comment: I tried with this one already. It works on single images, but not on image collections.

Comment: The combine function works for three bands, but combining more then 3 prompts the error of empty ImageCollection

Comment: You should show your code and error message, at least a link to the code editor

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1060f78574bd1d88c437f2b54ec5c36a

Comment: This is why you must post all the code (or a code that can reproduce the error) when you make the question.. `combine` function is what you need, but you are trying to combine collections that have images with different IDs, and if you see `combine` documentation it says that combines by ID, so when applying a join it doesn't find a match. If you want to join by date, you have to make the process yourself (join first and then add bands)

Comment: Can you elaborate the last part a bit?....

Because there was also another error in the same code. When i took mean of the bands into monthly data, it gave me the error of, "Pattern NDVI did not match any bands"
........
PS: Sorry about not posting my code earlier. I am new here, hence not very familiar with the rules of the town.